# I want to send USD amount instead of contract size in Strategy alerts in Pine script

Tags: pine-script

I want to send the usd amount of the contract, instead of the contract order, to the wundertrading bot from the dca strategy I created in the pine script. This is required to order futures in Wundertrading.
(DCA doesn't work properly when manually change contract qty for required USD amount)
Please help me.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it in the strategy options:

```
strategy(title="Example - order sizing based on cash amount",
 default_qty_type=strategy.cash)
```

Also to set USD as currency you can use:

```
strategy(title="Example - strategy that trades an euro account",
 currency=currency.USD)
```

With default_qty_type=strategy.cash, orders are sized based on a cash amount, but that doesn’t necessarily equal the capital investment. Let’s say a S&P 500 Index CFD has a 5% margin requirement and trades at 1,500. With a orders of 10,000 cash (default_qty_value=10000), TradingView computes the order size as 6 contracts (10,000 / 1,500 = 6.67 ≈ 6). However, the margin requirement is 75 per contract (5% * 1,500) and so the ‘investment’ is 450 (75 margin requirement times 6 contracts).

More info in this link:
https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/order-size-cash-currency/